# How to provide password to sqlite3.exe?

Tags: sqlite, encryption

I have a sqlite database that I want to open using sqlite3.exe. Now I get an error when I try to make queries, saying "file is encrypted or is not a database". This may seem stupid but I've been looking around on internet and I just don't find how to supply a password (or key) to sqlite3.exe to decrypt the database. The -help option or .help command of sqlite3.exe don't show anything to do that... Is it possible to do that, and if so how can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure the file is a valid sqlite database, and is not corrupted?

Comment: I'm not sure since someone sent it to me by email, but I know what the password is supposed to be if it's a valid encrypted database. That's why I want to validate it. If I provide a password to sqlite3 and I still get this error, than it would be a sign that the database is corrupted, but for now I've not found out how to provide a password.

Comment: And the guy who sent it to me by email is on vacation for 2 weeks so I can't ask him how to do that. But he gave me a password so I suppose my database is encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that the database would be encrypted, unless you have a reason to believe it is. Are you able to open the database at all, or are you getting this error once you issue some SQL query? If it's the former, your file is probably either not an sqlite db to begin with, or it is corrupted; if it's the latter, please check the integrity of your db with:

```
pragma integrity_check;
```

See http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check for more info about this pragma.

In any case, unless your db is really encrypted (which sqlite does not support natively), your db is probably unusable.

Comment: I get the error once I issue some SQL query. SQLite3.exe doesn't complain at first if I do sqlite3.exe myDBname.db

Comment: Yeah sorry bout that, I forgot that sqlite will just not complain until it actually does something with the db. Can you inspect that file and see if it looks encrypted (like by opening it with notepad)?

Comment: I don't know what an encrypted database is supposed to look like, but there are lots of unreadable characters and from time to time a name I recognize (for example, the names of the tables in the database).

Comment: I suppose this means the database is not encrypted and is just corrupted right?

Comment: If you recognize table names, I would assume that your db is not encrypted, at least not as a whole. At this point my best guess is that the email transmission messed with the the file. If you have linux lying around somewhere you can always file it: "file the_db_file"

Comment: Unfortunately we're on windows only here. Anyway thanks for the help I think I'll just try getting another (hopefully un-corrupted) test database.

Comment: Just to be sure the file comes in unchanged, get it zipped or something  first. Also, you can ask the sender to md5 it and so you'll be able to check the integrity; also make sure you have a compatible sqlite (eg ver 2 vs. ver 3)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite reports that error when you pass it a file which is either not actually a SQLite database, or alternatively has been corrupted. There are several SQLite addons to support encryption, but other than that SQLite doesn't have encryption.

It can also happen when you try and open a SQLite v3 database with SQLite v2 (and possibly for other version mismatches).

Assuming you have experienced corruption (and not just passing the wrong file, or using the wrong version of SQLite), you may want to check the `PRAGMA synchronous` settings you're using, and also review [the list of fixed data-corrupting bugs](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseCorruption).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this this [forum here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/112731-sqlite-with-password/). The guy had the same question as you. The thing is that there is not any form of protection offered as a standard package in sqlite3 API, but you can try [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). These are the codes posted on the forum:

```
#include <SQLite.au3>    don't include sqlite.dll.au3 !!!

_SQLite_Startup ("System.Data.SQLite.dll")
ConsoleWrite(_SQLite_LibVersion() & @LF)
_SQLite_Open("testcrypt.db")
_SQLite_Exec(-1, "pragma key = 'Radu is happy!';create table if not exists test (id integer, val text);" & _
                "insert into test values (1, 'abc');")
Local $row
_SQLite_QuerySingleRow(-1, "select * from test;", $row)
ConsoleWrite($row[1] & @LF)
_SQLite_Close()
_SQLite_Shutdown()
```

hope that helps.